# What is the best way to schedule a brief task from an already running background service?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, timertask, android-jobscheduler

I have implemented a NotificationListenerService that runs in the background.

From this services onNotificationPosted method, I would like to be able to queue work to happen in 2 minutes time.

What is the best way to go about this?

Both JobScheduler and Workmanager have a minimum interval of 15 minutes. Because I already have a background service running, I don't think I really need to use those, correct?

Could I just use something like a TimerTask, or even a sleep in my onNotificationPosted method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WorkManager` has 15 minutes interval only for periodic tasks, thats is not what you want, as I can see. You can schedule task with `OneTimeWorkRequest` to let it be executed in 2 minutes after the `onNotificationPosted` method call.

As you already have running service, you can probably just delay your task in separate coroutine scope

```
launch {
    delay(2 * 60 * 1000)
    yourTask()
}
```

or use

```
handler.postDelayed(2 * 60 * 1000) {
    yourTask()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the alternate approach!